# Cannot pass the entered variable from a function to a .py script

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a GUI, which will take the data date entered by the user and pass it to a python script that would be executed when a button is pressed in the GUI. My code looks like this as of now:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

main_gui = tk.Tk()
main_gui.title("Widefield Analysis")
main_gui.geometry("600x500")
datadate = StringVar()

def data_date():
    global ddate
    ddate = datadate.get()
    ddate_label.config()
    return ddate
    
def image_files(ddate):
    global varlist1
    from Image_files import filepath, filepath2, list1, filelist2
    varlist1 = [filepath, filepath2, list1, filelist2]
    return varlist1

ddate_label = Label(main_gui, text='Enter Data Date', font='Ariel 13 bold')
ddate_label.pack()
ddate_label.place(x=20, y=13)

date = tk.Entry(main_gui, textvariable=datadate, font='Ariel 13 normal', width=10)
date.place(x=205, y=10)
    
button1 = tk.Button(main_gui, text="Done", font="Ariel 13 bold", command=lambda:[data_date(), image_files(ddate)])
button1.place(x=500, y=450)


main_gui.mainloop()
```

The main idea is to take the datadate entered by the user and feed it to the Image_files.py script (which is a part of the image_files function, that gets executed when the "Done" button gets pressed). From the Image_files.py script, I need to return these variables: filepath, filepath2, list1, filelist2, which will later be used for other scripts being run in the same GUI. I am unable to do it now and need help.

I'm providing the code for the Image_files.py script here as well:

```
#THIS CODE PRECEEDS THE Image_stack.py CODE

import os

#datadate = input("Enter data date: ")
datadate = "17032020"
filepath = ("/home/abhra/Documents/My_first_code/" + datadate)

os.chdir(filepath)
#print("Current Working Directory ", os.getcwd()) **TO KNOW WHAT IS THE CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY**
filelist = os.listdir()
filecount = 0

#CREATES ARRAY FOR TSERIES FILES
for x in range (0,len(filelist),1):
    aa = filelist[x].startswith("TSeries")
    if aa == True:
        filecount = filecount + 1
list1 = [0] * filecount

counter=0
for y in range (0,len(filelist),1):
    bb = filelist[y].startswith("TSeries")
    if bb == True:
        list1[counter] = filelist[y]
        counter = counter+1
        
del aa, bb, x, y
list1.sort() #good initial sort but doesnt sort numerically very well
sorted(list1) #sort numerically in ascending order


#IMPORT STUFF FROM .mat FILE FROM PP_FILES
filepath2 = ("/home/abhra/Documents/My_first_code/" + datadate + "/" + "PP_FILES")
os.chdir(filepath2)
filelist2 = os.listdir()
filelist2.sort()
sorted(filelist2)

os.chdir("/home/abhra/Documents/My_first_code/")
```

Comment: define a function in the `Image_files` module and import it in the GUI script, then use it there and pass the user given values to that function, there is enough info out there about how to import own modules and use functions from them and stuff

Comment: @Matiiss: Can you please write a few lines of code? I am new to GUI making and would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: it is not about GUI, it is about defining a function with parameters and importing it in the other file, you already seem to know how to get data from the GUI, you just need to put that data in a function

Comment: @Matiiss: I did it finally, thanks for the input!